# ImportError: The 'packaging.requirements' package is required

Tags: python, python-2.7, gunicorn, setuptools

I'm running VPS with ubuntu:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I tried to upgrade Python to 2.7.16 from 2.7.6.

Just after upgrade Gunicorn library failed to start with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gunicorn import util
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 61, in load_module
    "distribution.".format(**locals())
ImportError: The 'packaging.requirements' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
```

I was told that it could be some setuptools issue, so I renewed them with

```
python -m ensurepip
Looking in links: /tmp/tmp98U8zf
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (41.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (19.2.2)
```

(no changes)

I tried to do

```
pip install packaging
```

(no changes)

or downgrade setuptools to 19.2 (as suggested in [Python 2.7 The 'packaging' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257738/python-2-7-the-packaging-package-is-required-normally-this-is-bundled-with-th))

and got

```
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py", line 8, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/home/user/bin/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Is there any working way to upgrade to 2.7.16 python in my case?

**UPD**:

I upgraded python with it with

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.16/Python-2.7.16.tgz
make clean && ./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared --prefix=/home/user/bin/python-2.7/ --with-ensurepip=install && make && make install
pip install -r ~/django/django_projects/requirements.txt
```

pip freeze: https://www.pastiebin.com/5d592ea701503

Thanks.

Comment: how did you upgrade your python?

Comment: and whats does your pip freeze show?

Comment: @Mox I added details to the bottom of the post.

Comment: i suggest that you create a separate virtual machine and use pyenv to config your python version to see if the same issue happens. This is just to make sure that the issue was not related to how you upgraded your python on ubuntu

Comment: Try purging pip from your system and reinstall it with the [recommended method](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: Seems like your *\_weakref.so* was not updated (belongs to the old version). Wipe your old version up, and then build the new one. Or better start from clean:  e.g. passing `--prefix=/home/user/bin/python-2.7.16/ `, so you know for sure which version is which (you can have multiple versions installed). Also (not sure about this), instead of `make install` try `make altinstall`.

Answer (score 3):

## Scenario

**First:** When trying to execute a Python script, the following error message appears:

```
ImportError: The 'packaging.requirements' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
```

**Second:** When trying to check the version of `setuptools` with `pip show setuptools` (or when using any other `pip` command), the next error message appears:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

## Reason

This is because the current Python installation is somehow screwed up. In my case the mess was caused by an upgrade from `Ubuntu 16.04` to `Ubuntu 18.04`.

## Solution

#### With Virtual Environment

In the best case you were already using a virtual environment (this was my case). The solution here would be to recreate/setup your venv again ([step-by-step](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RebuildingVirtualenvs/)):

```
$ cd /path/to/your/venv

# remove your old venv
$ rm -rf ./*

# create a new one
$ /usr/bin/virtualenv . --python=YOUR-PYTHON-VERSION

# activate venv
$ source bin/activate

# verify the correct python version is installed
$ python --version
```

For example replace `YOUR-PYTHON-VERSION` with `python2.7` or `python3.7`.

After recreating your venv the problem should be fixed and you should be able to use pip again.

#### Without Virtual Environment

I think the best way to fix the problem would be to completely uninstall all non-default Python versions (for example `Ubuntu 18.04` comes with `Python 3.6+`) and then make a clean reinstall of all other Python versions needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading pip by typing:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: or pip uninstall setuptools
pip install setuptools=='latest'

Comment: It didn't help.